# Disable touch on screen when dark

Tags: touchscreen

I'm running a pi3 with official 7 inch touchscreen and chromium in kiosk mode. The screen goes dark after a minute and wakens with a touch, which is what I want. But it also passes that touch to the browser. Is there a way to not pass that first touch to the browser, or have it respond to touch only if the screen is lit? Thanks.

Comment: what blanks the screen? ... is it the RPi, or is it the screen itself?